# Remove duplicated rows in more than one column using one line of code

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame and want to remove duplicates for multiple columns all together, it's faster and looks nice.

I tried this:

```
dataframe = dataframe [!duplicated(dataframe [c("Column1", "Column2", "Column3)]),]
```

Using this, the code runs without errors, but nothing changes. No rows are deleted when I check with `dim()`.

When I delete duplicates using this code, it works:

```
dupli = duplicated(dataframe$Column1) 
dataframe = dataframe[!dupli,]

dupli = duplicated(dataframe$Column2)
dataframe = dataframe[!dupli,]

dupli = duplicated(dataframe$Column3)
dataframe = dataframe[!dupli,]
```

Now the duplicates have been deleted. So there are definitely duplicates in these columns. So what's wrong with the line of code with them all together?

Comment: It is possible that  there are only unique values when the columns are grouped together i.e. check `library(dplyr); count(dataframe, Column1, Column2, Column3)` if the frequency count are all 1, then there are no dupes.  Your second piece of code is based on individual columns separately.  If you want to remove dupe rows if any of the column values have dupes, then do `i1 <- Reduce("|", lapply(dataframe [c("Column1","Column2","Column3)], function(x) !duplicated(x))); dataframe[i1,]`

Comment: @akrun hey akrun. The code you provided gives me a bolian vector. I tried applying it on my data with `df = df[i1,]` but still nothing changed.

Comment: Try it with this sample data for instance: `set.seed(1); 
dataframe <- as.data.frame(
    replicate(3, sample(letters, 10, replace=TRUE), simplify=FALSE),
    col.names=paste0("Column", 1:3)
)
`

Comment: @thelatemail Apparently I'm not applying it on my data correctly. Could you please tell me how to do that? Because in the sample data you provided it didn't work either.  the `i1` gives ten times the value `True`.  I don't understand how to use this bolian vector to delete the duplications.

Comment: Apologies, a slight adjustment needed to Akrun's solution - `il <- !Reduce("|", lapply(dataframe[c("Column1","Column2","Column3")], function(x) duplicated(x)))` then `dataframe[il,]`